# Dynamically Storing Multiple Values in a JavaScript String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic button with a class of 'compare-btn' and an ID that's unique to each product where the button resides.

When this button is clicked, I have created a script that grabs the ID of the button and sets a JS variable equal to the value, see below:

```
  $(".compare-btn").click(function() {
    var contentPanelId = $(this).attr("id");

    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "compare.php",
      // data: { data1: contentPanelId, data2: value2, data3: value3 }
      data: { data1: contentPanelId }
    })

    .done(function(html) {
      console.log(contentPanelId);
    })

    .fail(function(html) {
      // Fail
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

What I would like to do is store three values instead of one. For example, if buttons with an ID of 1, 2 and 3 were clicked, then the data object would contain data1: 1, data2: 2 and data3: 3. However, I'm unsure how I can change the following code to make it work as described...

```
$(".compare-btn").click(function() {
var contentPanelId = $(this).attr("id");
```

Comment: It's not clear what your goal is. Given this statement: `the data object would contain data1: 1, data2: 2 and data3: 3` do you mean that you want to hard-code the value sent in the request? How does the date change depending on the button which is clicked?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, each button has the same class which the click function runs from, but the value of the ID attribute is different. I need to make it so that when you click three compare buttons, data1, data2 and data3 are equal to the value of each 'clicked' button.

Comment: But you can only click one button at a time...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes I understand you can only click one button at a time. But I need to collect the value of three buttons which are clicked and store them in the object: data: { data1: contentPanelId_1, data2: contentPanelId_2, data3: contentPanelId_3 }

Comment: Right, I understand. In that case give each button a class when it's clicked, eg. `active`. Then select the `.active` elements and retrieve their `id` attributes to place in the objects. The issue is now that you need a method to deselect the buttons. As such it would make more sense to ***only*** toggle the `active` class when the buttons are clicked, then add a new 'submit' button which sends the AJAX request. You could also turn the individual buttons in to toggle checkboxes, as that seems to suit their purpose far better.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should store id in an array. That way, you can extend to sort as many as you want.

```
    var list_id = []
    var limit = 3
    $(".compare-btn").click(function() {
      var contentPanelId = $(this).attr("id");
      if (list_id.length == limit) {
        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "compare.php",
          data: { list_id: list_id }
        })
        .done(function(html) {
          console.log(list_id);
          list_id = []  // optional: clear list after compare
        })
        .fail(function(html) {
          // Fail
        });
      } else {
        list_id.push(contentPanelId)
      }
    });
```